# Django REST API get only auth user datas

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new Django, I try make REST API. Now face one issue. I created 2 models Account & Transaction

```
class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Account have ForeignKey with user model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(),primary_key=True,editable=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='account')
    transaction_no = models.CharField(default=str(uuid.uuid4())[:8],max_length=100)
```

Transaction have ForeignKey with Account model. then get JWT token & pass on API. In `view.py` I filtered by requested user

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getAccount(request,pk):
    account = Account.objects.filter(user=request.user).get(id=pk)
    serializer = AccountSerializer(account, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

now how will filter Transaction only by auth User

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getTransactions(request,account_id):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(account=account_id)
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(transactions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getTransactions(request):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(account__user=request.user)
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(transactions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here we thus retrieve `Transaction`s for which the `account` refers to an `Account` object with `request.user` as `user`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).